# Understanding Definition of $p$th-Order Total Differential

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

- Define higher-order differentials. Let $p \geq 1,$ let $V$ be open in $\mathbf{R}^{n},$ let $\boldsymbol{a} \in V,$ and let
  $f: V \rightarrow \mathbf{R} .$ We shall say that $f$ has a pth-order total differential at $a$ if and only if
  the $(p-1)$ st-order partial derivatives of $f$ exist on $V$ and are differentiable at $a$, in
  which case we shall use the notation

$$D^{(p)} f(\boldsymbol{\alpha}, \boldsymbol{h}):=\sum_{i_{1}=1}^{n} \cdots \sum_{i_{p}=1}^{n} \frac{\partial^{p} f}{\partial x_{i_{1}} \ldots \partial x_{i_{p}}}(\boldsymbol{a}) h_{i_{1}} \cdots h_{i_{p}}, \quad \boldsymbol{h}=\left(h_{1}, \ldots, h_{n}\right) \in \mathbf{R}^{n}$$

**Example.** Suppose that $f: V \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ is $C^{2}$ on $V .$ Find a formula for the
second total differential of $f$ at $(a, b) \in V$

Solution. By definition,
$D^{(2)} f((a, b) ;(h, k))=h^{2} \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}(a, b)+h k \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x \partial y}(a, b)+h k \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial y \partial x}(a, b)+k^{2} \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial y^{2}}(a, b)$
But by a thereom $ f_{x y}(a, b)=f_{y x}(a, b) .$ Therefore,
$$
D^{(2)} f((a, b) ;(h, k))=h^{2} \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}(a, b)+2 h k \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x \partial y}(a, b)+k^{2} \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial y^{2}}(a, b) .
$$

**My question is:**

- Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by
  $$
  f(x, y, z)=x^{2}+z^{2}+y z+2 \cos (x+y z)
  $$
  (a) How can I find $D f (p;h)$? (as $p,h\in\mathbb{R^3}$)

  (b) How can I find $D^{(2)} f(p;h)$? (as $p,h\in\mathbb{R^3}$)

My Attempt. $D^{(2)}f((a,b,c);(h,k,p))=h^2\dfrac{\partial^2 f} {\partial x^2}(a,b,c)+k^2\dfrac{\partial^2 f} {\partial y^2}(a,b,c)+p^2\dfrac{\partial^2 f} {\partial z^2}(a,b,c)+2hk\dfrac{\partial^2 f} {\partial xy}(a,b,c)+2hp\dfrac{\partial^2 f} {\partial xz}(a,b,c)+2kp\dfrac{\partial^2 f} {\partial yz}(a,b,c)$

May you check $D^{(2)}f((a,b,c);(h,k,p))$ in the my  attempt?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Is this the new question you told me about whilE deleting your old post? I promise to have a better look at it, and apologize for last time

Comment: The expression you write for your double derivative in your attempt is correct. However, it remains in the case of $f(x,y,z) = x^2+z^2+yz + 2\cos(x+yz)$ to compute the exact values of $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(a,b,c)$ etc.and substitute them in the expression.